# SQL Column duplicates matching different values

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlfire

I have a table in which i am trying to show the different years in which something was released. i have:

```
Name    Releasedate   Releasedate
Item 1  2001          2001
Item 1  2001          2001
Item 1  2001          2001
```

and the type of thing i want to end up with is:

```
Name    Releasedate   Releasedate
Item 1  2001          2002
Item 1  2001          2003
Item 1  2002          2003
```

This way it shows different release dates side by side without showing duplicates, or switching the order around ie. 2001-2002 -> 2002-2001

Comment: Do you always want them to be ordered such that the first column is the smaller value?

Comment: You have two columns with the same name?

Comment: I think he's joining a table on itself

Comment: yes, the first column should be of a smaller value. this is all done with the one table, but i havent got any joins made. i currently have only this:
select Name, Releasedate, Releasedate
from Table
where Name in (
    select Name
    from Table
    group by Name
    having (count(Name)>1))

Comment: Would you be better off getting your data to return as [Item 1]|[2001]|[2002]|[2003], effectively presenting all of the release dates for an item on a single row?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some table named tableName where the schema is Name, Releasedate

```
select a.Name, a.Releasedate, b.Releasedate 
from tableName a, tableName b
where a.Name = b.Name and a.Releasedate < b.Releasedate
```

Answer (score 0):

If you means to find out duplicate values then this will help you. [Check this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18656185/2481557)

OR try this one

```
Select 
    a.Name,a.releasedate, 
    b.Name,b.releasedate
From table a
    Join table b 
        On a.name = b.name 
            and a.releasedate < b.releasedate And a.rowid < b.rowid
```